# error en la compilación

Tags: vb.net, scanner

Hola buenas noches estoy compilando el siguiente código realizado con el fin de poder utilizar la dll twaindotnet todos los ejemplos que baje son incompletos por las necesidades que requiero mayormente que scanne en adf , color y guarde en una dirección establecida

```
public static DataSource GetDefault(Identity applicationId, IWindowsMessageHook messageHook)
{
    var defaultSourceId = new Identity();
    // Attempt to get information about the system default source
    var result = Twain32Native.DsmIdentity(
        applicationId,
        IntPtr.Zero,
        DataGroup.Control,
        DataArgumentType.Identity,
        Message.GetDefault,
        defaultSourceId);
    if (result != TwainResult.Success)
    {
        var status = DataSourceManager.GetConditionCode(applicationId, null);
        throw new TwainException("Error getting information about the default source: " + result, result, status);
    }
    return new DataSource(applicationId, defaultSourceId, messageHook)
}
```

Me da el siguiente error System.AccessViolationException: Intento de leer o escribir en la memoria protegida. A menudo, esto indica que hay otra memoria dañada.
el tema es que cuando lo compilo en otra maquina no surge nada son las dos de 64 bits en vs 2019 corrí el análisis de memoria en el la que da error y no pude encontrar error  es una aplicación que usa el ejemplo de twaindotnet de git tendré que desinstalar formatear es un problema de el frame
no tengo mas detalles que agregar no me deja publicar la pregunta por falta de detalles